# PyAIML Sessions not working

Tags: python, session, aiml

I expect I'm doing something wrong here, but whenever I try to insert the [snippet to save session information](http://pyaiml.sourceforge.net/#examples) for the chatbot, the terminal closes immediately with an error.  Here's my source:

```
import aiml
k = aiml.Kernel()
#k.learn("std-startup.xml")
#k.respond("load aiml b")
#k.saveBrain("test.brn")
k.loadBrain("test.brn")
#while True: print k.respond(raw_input("> "))
keepAlive = True
while True: 
    output = k.respond(raw_input("> "))
    print output,
    session = k.getSessionData("Bob")
    sessionFile = file("Bob.ses", "wb")
    marshal.dump(session, sessionFile)
    sessionFile.close()
```

[image: new error]

Comment: Where is full error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you need to use `k` in place of `Kernel`

```
session = k.getSessionData("Bob")
```

Comment: In place of `session = Kernel.getSessionData("Bob")`. But I'm only guessing that you need `aiml.`

Comment: I'm getting an NameError saying 'marshal' is not defined (which it's not; I'm just going by the example on the site)

Comment: Okay works fine now, but doesn't save the session data (because I just close the terminal to exit the program which, I'm guessing, doesn't give it the chance to save the session.  Should I move the comma to the very end of the loop?  Or perhaps make it so when I enter something like 'exit', it ends the loop and saves the file then closes the terminal?

Comment: What comma do you mean ?

Comment: The one after 'print output'

Comment: You can't move it but I think you don't need it . You can delete comma.

Comment: The problem is that the session gets lost (sort of defeating the purpose of it)

Comment: Why ? What do you mean ? What did you expect ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56497/discussion-between-n-soong-and-furas).

Answer (score 0):

```
print bot.respond(raw_input(">"), "Bob")
```